# HTML5 Canvas Drawing Multiple PNG images with transparency

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, png, transparency

I have an html5 page with multiple png images on it that have transparent backgrounds.  I am trying to draw them all on a single canvas object and maintain the transparency between them.  I keep getting them drawn where they should be, but with a black background.  The images are already loaded on the page, so it is not an onLoad issue.  I am using the clearRect method on the canvas before I loop through my images.  Here is the loop I am running to draw the images.  (The lines to get left, top, width and height are all working as desired.  The issue is with the drawImage line.)  Images is a collection of img elements on the page with images visible.

```
            for (i = 0; i < Images.length; i++) {
                imgTop = parseInt(Images[i].style.top) - Top;
                imgLeft = parseInt(Images[i].style.left) - Left;
                imgWidth = parseInt(Images[i].style.width);
                imgHeight = parseInt(Images[i].style.height);
                ctx.drawImage(Images[i], imgLeft, imgTop, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            }
```

Comment: To clarify, are you getting an opaque black background where you're expecting transparency on each image?  Are you using .getImageData & .putImageData to modify the images?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error of my ways.  It had nothing to do with the code I posted.  When I was done creating the canvas, I was using toDataURL with the parameter to create a jpeg rather than a png.  When I changed to PNG it worked as desired.